# Is It Possible To Sign Messi on Career mode With Man. City

Tags: fifa-16

I have tried buying Messi and giving him a wage of 1.1 million a week but he still won't join. I am currently Man. City.

Comment: I know nothing about Fifa 16 but are you sure it's Messi refusing to move and not Barcelona refusing to release him?

Comment: Messi wont want to move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is basically impossible to sign Messi. Just play as Barca, and you get to play with him. Other than that, maybe try to sign him in a few seasons time?

Answer (score 0):

Me being man City I offered Barca 45 mil plus ageuro and signed messi on a 500,000 a week in wages expensive but affordable if you have won many trophies